# React - Django connection: Data in Heroku app lost

Tags: reactjs, django, database, heroku

I am using a Django app as a backend on Heroku and a React app as a frontend at my local machine. The apps are used for creating blog posts. They have worked quite well so far. I created several posts, and these posts were seen on the server and could be retrieved for frontend. However, when I came back from the night (sleeping), these posts were disappeared. I do not know how to solve that problem.

Your suggestion and explanation would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using and what heroku plan are you on?

Comment: SQLite and free

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku file system is ephemeral and only lasts until while that dyno is running. Eventually the dyno is restarted with a clean copy of the filesystem. From an official [help article](https://Here%20is%20the%20help%20article%20referencing%20this%20particular%20issue:%20%20https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted):

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
> filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
> container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

This means that your database, SQLite, which depends on a file being persisted will be effectively destroyed and re-created every day. You would either need to host that database file somewhere such as S3 or use a database service/instance that persists.